# How to prove that this collection is a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathscr{U}$ denote the usual or standard topology on the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers.

Let $\{ p \}$ be any singleton set such that $p \not\in \mathbb{R}$, let $\mathbb{R}^* = \mathbb{R} \cup \{ p \}$, and let $\mathscr{T}$ denote the collection of all the $\mathscr{U}$-open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and the collection of the complements relative to $\mathbb{R}^*$ of all the closed bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, that is,
$$
\mathscr{T} = \mathscr{U} \bigcup \left\{ \mathbb{R}^* \setminus S \colon S \subset \mathbb{R}, S \mbox{ is bounded}, \mathbb{R} \setminus S \in \mathscr{U} \right\}
$$
or
$$
\mathscr{T} = \mathscr{U} \bigcup \big\{ \{ p \} \cup ( \mathbb{R} \setminus S ) \colon S \subset \mathbb{R}, S \mbox{ is bounded}, \mathbb{R} \setminus S \in \mathscr{U} \big\}.
$$

How is this collection a topology on $\mathbb{R}^*$?

My Attempt:

> Since $\emptyset$ is a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, therefore $\mathbb{R}^* \setminus \emptyset = \mathbb{R}^* \in \mathscr{T}$. And, since $\emptyset \in \mathscr{U}$, therefore $\emptyset \in \mathscr{T}$ also.

> Let $S$ and $T$ be any two sets in $\mathscr{T}$. We show that $S \cap T$ is also in $\mathscr{T}$.

> If $S$ and $T$ both are in $\mathscr{U}$, then so is $S \cap T$ and hence $S \cap T$ also in $\mathscr{T}$.

> If $S \in \mathscr{U}$ and $T = \mathscr{R}^* \setminus A$, where $A$ is a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $S \cap T = S \cap ( \mathbb{R} \setminus A )$, which is in $\mathscr{U}$ and hence also in $\mathscr{T}$.

> If $S = \mathscr{R}^* \setminus A$ and $T = \mathscr{R}^* \setminus B$, where $A$ and $B$ are closed bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then
> $$
> S \cap T = \left( \mathscr{R}^* \setminus A \right) \cap \left( \mathscr{R}^* \setminus B \right) = \mathscr{R}^* \setminus ( A \cup B),
> $$
> and $A \cup B$ is a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, thus showing that $S \cap T$ is in $\mathscr{T}$.

> Let $\mathscr{T}_0$ be an arbitrary subcollection of $\mathscr{T}$. If $\mathscr{T}_0 \subset \mathscr{U}$, then we obviously have
> $$
> \bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{T}_0} S \in \mathscr{U},
> $$
> because $\mathscr{U}$ is a topology (on $\mathbb{R}$). So let us assume that $\mathscr{T}_0 \setminus \mathscr{U} \neq \emptyset$. Let us put
> $$
> \mathscr{T}_1 := \mathscr{T}_0 \setminus \mathscr{U} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \mathscr{U}_0 := \mathscr{T}_0 \setminus \mathscr{T}_1.
> $$
> Then of course
> $$
> \mathscr{U}_0 \subset \mathscr{U}, 
> $$
> and so $\bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{U}_0} S$ is in $\mathscr{U}$ and hence also in $\mathscr{T}$.

> Thus we have
> \begin{align}
> \bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{T}_0} S &= \left( \bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{T}_1} S \right) \bigcup \left( \bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{U}_0} S \right)
> \end{align}

> If the collection $\mathscr{T}_1$ is finite, then we have
> $$
> \mathbb{R}^* \setminus \left( \bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{T}_1} S \right)  = \bigcap_{S \in \mathscr{T}_1} \left( \mathbb{R}^* \setminus S \right). 
> $$
> which is a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, thus showing that $ \bigcup_{S \in \mathscr{T}_1} S \in \mathscr{T}$.

What if $\mathscr{T}_1$ is infinite?

What next? How to proceed from here?

Comment: Let $\mathscr T_1=\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$, then every $S_i\in\mathscr T_1$ has the form $\mathbb R^*\setminus B_i$, with $B_i$ closed and bounded, so $$\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i=\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathbb R^*\setminus B_i=\mathbb R^*\setminus\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i\right)$$and arbitrary intersection of closed bounded sets is still closed and bounded.